# Must I call sendResponse?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am using `chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener`, I see that I am calling sendResponse with no arguments (`=> sendResponse();` ), Sometimes I get an error like this: 
`Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object`

Must I call sendResponse, or I can remove this function if I am not expecting to get a response from the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#event-onRequest) says:

> Function to call (at most once) when you have a response.

This "at most once" sort of indicates that sending a response is optional. While I won't be able to get you an official confirmation, I checked the source code of my extension and there are several messages where `sendResponse` isn't being called - so far (after a year of heavy use) no issues.

Comment: Not calling `sendResponse` used to cause memory leaks, but this will be fixed in Chrome 19 (see http://crrev.com/126884).